# Cutting digits of a number without approximation:

Tags: lazy-computations, computational-complexity

I am evaluating an exponential and I end up with the following result:

$1.4497788553129478854329$

Is there a command on Mathematica that allows me to cut my result without approximating it? I would need 1.44 only to carry out another calculation.

I tried using NumberForm with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "cut my result without approximating it". Anyways, `NumberForm` is only for display purposes (like almost all commands ending with `Form`). Maybe you are asking for `Round[1.4497788553129478854329,0.01]` or `Floor[1.4497788553129478854329, 0.01]`?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have about 23 digits of precision here. The result of a controlled precision calculation?

```
x=1.4497788553129478854329`23
(* 1.4497788553129478854329 *)
```

Anyway, if you want subsequent calculations to be fast, simply use `N`:

```
N[x]
(* 1.44978 *)
```

Note that the actual precision here is about 16 digits, but `Mathematica` only displays 6. Calculations using this as input will use fast "machine" arithmetic without precision tracking.

You may also do:

```
N[x,3]
(* 1.45 *)
```

Less precise, but *Mathematica* tracks precision of such numbers through calculations. This is slower than using machine numbers.